# PHP Копирование файлов и права доступа

Tags: php, linux, bash

В веб приложении использую копирование файлов с одной папки сервера в другую с помощью команды:

```
system("cp -r $from $to");
```

Проблема в том, что owner и group у скопированных файлов получается www-data. И в итоге текущий юзер не имеет прав на редактирование этих файлов.

Какие есть варианты решения проблемы? Может ли php копировать файлы от имени юзера или может как-то правильно настроить права групп и юзеров, что бы не надо было заходить ручками в шелл и править юзера и группу на нужную

Comment: добавь текужего узера в www-data и перезайди или пользуйся umask

Comment: umask, suid, guid, sticky - делает то что нужно, но там голову можно сломать без опыта. Лучше ACL http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list запустить

Comment: Что за файлы вы перемещаете, откуда и куда?

Answer (score 1):

Даёте пользователю www-data доступ через sudo к `chown` - команде для изменения владельца файла.
Для этого:

1) открываете из терминала **/etc/sudoers**

```
$ sudo visudo
```

2) добавляете такую строку:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/chown-my-files
```

3) в /usr/local/bin/chown-my-files

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -d $1 ] && chown other-user $1
```

4) устанавливаете права на запуск этой обертки

```
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/chown-my-files
$ chown root /usr/local/bin/chown-my-files
```

Дальше в php скрипте вызываете `chown`:

```
shell_exec("sudo /usr/local/bin/chown-my-files \"$path-to-file\"");
```

Comment: не делайте так никогда!

Comment: @eri Вы могли бы добавить "почему" к ответу или в комментарий - и я бы с радостью добавил это в ответ. К несчастью, я не помню, есть ли возможность дать более узкие права на изменение, например, только для файлов в определённой директории. Не напомните?

Comment: Потому что находим уязвимость на сайте и делаем `chown www-data /etc/shadow` или какую-нибудь подобную пакость

Comment: @svgrafov делаешь скрипт с захардкодеными путями и судо разрешай только на него

Comment: Но, по-моему, если сделать какую-нибудь умную обёртку над chown, которая будет проверять корректность путей, то можно, но очень осторожно (а то уязвимости и в обёртке могут оказаться)

Comment: Исправил немного в плане безопасности, но всеравно не нравится мне этот метод

Comment: В текущем варианте я не думаю, что путь всегда один и тот же

Comment: @andreymal давай немного усложним. Вот так можно папку просунуть..